# c++ unique_ptr move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, smart-pointers

In another post was mentioned this doesn't work due to the different deleter types.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> ptr(nullptr);
std::unique_ptr<const char[]> ptr_2(std::move(ptr));
```

But there was no solution to achieve this behavior in VSS2013. Does somebody know a short and clean solution?

Edit::

```
std::unique_ptr<const char[]> ptr_2(ptr.release());
```

doesn't work and compiles with the error:

```
error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<const char [],std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr<char*>(_Ptr2)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=const char []
1>  ,            _Ptr2=char *
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\memory(1612) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<const char [],std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=const char []
1>          ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward `release` answer does not compile since Visual Studio defines constructor from another pointer type `template<class _Ptr2> explicit unique_ptr(_Ptr2)` as `private` so you must do it like this:

`std::unique_ptr<const char[]> ptr_2(const_cast<const char*>(ptr.release()));`

to make the pointer types match.

Comment: +1, although I would prefer to use `const_cast` since you only want to add `const` to the pointer type, not perform any other conversions.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I edited it, thanks, an answer should be precise.

Answer (score 4):

The wording in the published C++ standard says that conversions involving changes in const-qualification are not allowed for `unique_ptr<T[]>`. This is a defect, [DR 2118](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2118), which was resolved by the changes in [N4089](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4089.pdf).

Older compilers may not implement the new rules (I implemented an earlier version of the fix for GCC 4.8, but GCC didn't support it before then either).

Comment: +1:  Just surveyed online compilers and all three most recent implementations (libstdc++, libc++, VS) have the fix implemented (OP's code compiles).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, simply avoid the move and do it manually:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> ptr(nullptr);
std::unique_ptr<const char[]> ptr_2(ptr.release());
```

Comment: Hmm. I don't have access to a recent VS at the moment. What error does it give? (It works in g++...)

Answer (score 0):

You can always release:

```
std::unique_ptr<const char[]> ptr_2(ptr.release());
```

But be sure to add a comment pointing out why a simple move doesn't work.